# Box Python API - How to set SSL Certificate check as false?

Tags: python, api, ssl-certificate, box

Relatively new to python and box. Trying to connect to Box python API using below code:

```
from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2

oauth = OAuth2(
    client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    access_token='ACCESS_TOKEN',
    refresh_token='REFRESH_TOKEN',
)

client = Client(auth)

user = client.user().get()
print('User ID is {0}'.format(user.id))
```

And getting following error:

OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

How can I set cert verify to false? whats the process to store SSL certs? Using windows, python 3.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Box doesn't actively monitor/provide support via StackOverflow for the Box SDKs.  If you're still having issues, you may want to create a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/issues/new

Be sure to checkout the [README doc](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/blob/master/README.rst) and the [Usage docs](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/tree/master/docs/usage), first.  Also, the [demo app](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/tree/master/demo) has an [authentication example](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/blob/master/demo/auth.py) that may help you.